# Is using parseInt extraenous if unnecessary?

Tags: javascript, var, parseint

I am a beginner to coding and JavaScript but I am doing a practice exercise and I came across something I am unsure about.

```
var nameLength = parseInt(fullName.length);
var nameLength = fullName.length;
```

I used the first line not even thinking it would already be an integer, so should I still have included the parseInt or not?

Comment: No, why would you parse an integer if it's already an integer?

Comment: `parseInt` should only be called on strings. So what is `fullname.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, remove `var nameLength = parseInt(fullName.length);` Below is your explanation:
The parseInt() method in JavaScript is used to turn the integer value of a string into an integer. If I have string, say `var s = "3";`, I could use the + operator to it, but it wouldn't add as if they were numbers (ex. `s += 9;`, then `s` would equal `"39"`). You call the `parseInt()` method only if you have a value with the type of string. In your case, and in most, if not all languages, the `.length` or `.length()` of anything will return an integer. What you're doing is trying to convert a number to a number, which is (after I googled the definition) extraneous.

Comment: Haha, I'm better at vocabulary than coding it would seem. This is exactly what I was looking for thanks @AlexJone