# Difference in efficacy between parseInt() and Number.isInteger() in following Javascript array scenario?

Tags: javascript, syntax, parseint, code-organization

I am working through freecodecamp.org's Javascript ES6 coding problems and one of them tasked me with using arrow function notation to:

1. Take an array of real numbers.
2. Filter only the positive integers into a new array, and
3. Square those positive integers.

I have successfully completed the problem but built my code for Step 2 by filtering the original array with Numbers.isInteger(). Freecodecamp.org's provided answer utilizes parseInt().

I do not see why we would need to parse integers if they are already integers, nor why parseInt() does not throw an error since its parameter asks for a string.

**My primary question:** Are both equally acceptable? Is one going to get me into more trouble down the road?

The only closely relevant stackoverfow I found was  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882193/is-using-parseint-extraenous-if-unnecessary) (which was vaguely helpful). Below is my code followed by the answer code provided by freecodecamp.org. NOTE: I am aware my code has a few extra steps in it. I am not a huge fan of arrow notation and am still improving my code-organization!

---

*MY CODE::*

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const squareList = (arr) => {

"use strict";

// dictates what numbers are filter()'d out of original array

const checkElement = (value) => value > 0 && Number.isInteger(value) == true;

const integersOnly = arr.filter(checkElement); //filters ONLY positive integers into new array
```

---

*PROVIDED ANSWER CODE::*

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const squareList = (arr) => {

"use strict";

const squaredIntegers = arr.filter( (num) => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0 ).map( (num) => Math.pow(num, 2) );
```

Comment: You can format code in your post by editing it. There are buttons to format it as code. Which makes it way more readable to people trying to answer.

Comment: "*I am not a huge fan of arrow notation*" - then why are you doing `const checkElement = (value) => …;` instead of `function checkElement(value) { return  …; }`? :-P

Comment: @Todd Chaffee thank you for that clarification and doing it for me! I was trying to figure that out and will use from on now.

@Bergi; It is a requirement of the coding problem by the institution (freecodecamp) to use arrow notation, as a means for me to learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not see why we would need to parse integers if they are already integers.

You don't need to. This is abuse of `parseInt`. They should have used `Math.floor` instead for their intented purpose.

> Why `parseInt()` does not throw an error since its parameter asks for a string?

Because it's an old API, and it's very lenient. Instead of throwing errors, it simply coerces its argument to a string, then tries to parse that.

> My primary question: Are both equally acceptable?

No, `parseInt` is absolutely inacceptable. You found a much better solution with `isInteger`. The reason why they didn't use it probably is that `isInteger` is a relatively new function, added with ES6.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are a little bit misleading - the first parameter to `parseInt` doesn't *have* to be a string. Looking at the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2), the first argument gets cast to a string as the first step:

> When the parseInt function is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let inputString be ToString(string).

One of the problems with `parseInt` is that, if it has a leading zero, it may be interpreted as [octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763396/javascript-parseint-with-leading-zeros) in some (old) browsers, and as base 10 in other (newer) browsers. For this reason, if you want to support said old browsers, it's best to either always provide a radix (as the second parameter) or use `Number` instead.

That said, in this particular situation, it makes no difference, because calling `parseInt` on a number will never result in a leading zero.

Still, I think the recommended answer is a bit misleading - since you know that the numbers used in the test will always be positive, it would be a bit more appropriate to use `Math.floor` than `parseInt` for this purpose, since you're just trying to get the floored value, not trying to turn a string into a number.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt tries to convert the value you pass to it into an integer, if you call it with this parameter `parseInt("30")` it will return to you the value 30 as a number. If you call it with a value that can't be converted to a integer like `parseInt("hello world")` it will return NaN.

Number.isInteger validates if the given value is an integer returning a true or false boolean value. `Number.isInteger(1)` will return true, `Number.isInteger("hello world")` or `Number.isInteger(3.14)` will return false.